# Custom button to open a Lightning action NOT implementing force:quickAction

Tags: lightning-aura-components, quickaction

On a custom record I want to add a button that opens a Lightning component. This component is NOT a Quick Action and therefore should not be opened in modal.

Can I do this and how?

Comment: where do you want to open the component?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [force:navigateToComponent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToComponent.htm) which is currently in beta,

example component with a button that triggers the redirection:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" />
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        var event = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
        event.setParams({
                componentDef : "c:customComponent",
        });
        event.fire();
    }
})
```

It should work from your record page as far as testing goes